# changing directories by using cd

Tags: shell

I executed the following command :

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/Daniel/Documents/Assg/ | cat file.txt
```

my question is why doesn't it change directory?. The output file.txt is displayed but the directory is not changed. I understand that if we execute the same command in the following order, it won't work because cd changes directory in a child process, so the net result is the same.

```
cat file.txt | cd /mnt/c/Users/Daniel/Documents/Assg/
```

Comment: Using pipes (`|`) in this context makes no sense. They are supposed to connect output of one command to input of another command, but `cd` ignores standard input and `cat` ignores it when given a file argument.

Comment: When I go to `/var/tmp` and then issue `cd /etc/apt/ |cat sources.list`, my shell responds with: `cat: sources.list: No such file or directory`.  OP never specified what the original directory or its contents are.

Comment: @Fernando Please provide us with a reproducable example; Include an example of the alternate directory (does it work from /var/tmp?), and its contents. Also specify which shell you use and which OS+release.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld You are right. No such file error is issued. My previous impression was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try just `cd /mnt/c/Users/Daniel/Documents/Assg/`

Comment: Please consider adding additional information as to why this is the correct answer.  Code-only answers do not tend to be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

As was already stated, the following:

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/Daniel/Documents/Assg/
```

should do the trick, but I'd like to go a bit more into why the command you presented doesn't work as expected.  In Bash (and other shells), you can have multiple "subshells" running under a parent shell.  each of these subshells has its own working directory. When you run commands in a pipeline, as you have done, a subshell is created.  The working directory of the subshell was changed, but that didn't have any effect on the shell you were working in.

Comment: cd /mnt/c/Users/Daniel/Documents/Assg/  is supposed to run in the parent shell.  cat file.txt runs in the child shell.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou You fall into the same trap as OP.  `cd ...` and `echo ...` run in separate parallel processes;  `cd` in one does not affect `$PWD` in the other.

Answer (score 0):

You have different options.
Perform `cat` after trying to change dir

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/Daniel/Documents/Assg/ ; cat file.txt
```

Perform `cat` only when change dir worked

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/Daniel/Documents/Assg/ && cat file.txt
```

Perform `cat` in the other directory, but return to the current dir when finished.

```
(cd /mnt/c/Users/Daniel/Documents/Assg/ && cat file.txt)
# or
cat /mnt/c/Users/Daniel/Documents/Assg/file.txt
```

EDIT:
Your question: "why doesnt `cd /mnt/c/Users/Daniel/Documents/Assg/ | cat file.txt`, change directory?." can be answered two ways.
The technical explanation is given by @Henk (The pipe introduces a subshell, and environ settings in a subshell get lost when the shell exits).
The functional explanation is that you used the wrong syntax for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Can you answer the question and explain why the original command line does not work?

Answer (score 0):

**It depends on the shell you use**

When you run two commands in a pipeline, typically one or both of the commands is run in a separate child process.

In older shells this would be both, in later shells this can be either
the first *or* the last.

At one point, the ksh93 team decided to make the last command in the pipeline the parent.  This would prevent race conditions, and if the command was a builtin, it allows it to run inside the current shell 
process and preserve the results of the pipeline.

Nevertheless, `cd` is a command that does not consume or produce any input or output (except for diagnostics on stderr), and using it in a pipeline
by itself is just silly.  A better, because more predictable, command line would be:

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/Daniel/Documents/Assg/ && cat file.txt
```

This will assure that `cat` only runs if `cd` succeeds, and will then
show the contents of `file.txt` from the given directory.